# Getting String from textfield to another class null value[Java]

Tags: java, swing

Hello I'm sorry if this is answered before, I'm really tired and bored :/
What I'm trying to do is getText() from textField in Class1 to String in Class2:

In Class1:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
. . .
    public String getme() {
    return textField.getText();
}
```

And to get String in Class2:

```
String user = new Class1().getme();
```

This doesn't work.. it gets null value.

If i put raw value, like:

```
public String getme() {
    return "hm";
}
```

It does work.

Can you help, ty in advance!

Comment: because you use `new` keyword there  @mrEnthusiast

Comment: Try using, `JTextField textField = new JTextField("test");`

Comment: @Null What you are suggesting doesn't do anything. What does that have to do with strings being immutable?

Comment: You're creating a new instance of `Class1` and trying to get the text from it. Without much more context, I'd suggest that you should do some research into modal dialogs instead

Comment: Why do you say it is returning null? null is a specific value, is it returning an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new Class1 with a new JTextField inside. It's certainly the default behaviour of the getText() method on new objects.

Comment: Ye I fixed it, don't know why I put that new there... thanks to all anyway ;)